# Mixing IDs in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

couchDB by default generates IDs like 08b38673484804ee8ea07f464a0015a1 for new documents.
However, can I also mix in other IDs like guest10090087 ? so my documents will have couch generated ids and my own ids. would this affect performance and is it safe in the long run ?

assuming all my self generated ids are unique also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [recommended](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#A_id) to generate your own _ids. So yes if you can guarantee the uniqueness of the _id field using your own _ids is a good idea.